# error in reading CSV file for invisible data

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file with data upto 418 lines(rows) but my read function trying to read files even after end of the data. It may contains some invisible data

```
reader = csv.reader(open("C://Python27//tftable1.csv", 'r'))
data = []
for row in reader:
data.append(row)
```

I always need to delete last rows of the CSV file to work it without any problem. But because of this problem I am not able to access CSV file directly which is written by the program.

```
fdoc="C://Python27//tftable1.csv"
outfile=open(fdoc,"w")
outfile.write(tf_idf)
outfile.close()
```

Is there any solution to make it work?

Comment: You can open it with a editor like sublimetext or notepad++ and change the encode to look the phantom chars.

Comment: Can you provide a sample file?

Comment: @PedroRomano I did it. I just deleted some last words of `tf_idf` using `tf_idf[:-2]` and it worked.